# How to get the Span<Byte> to the HTTP request header in Kestrel

Tags: asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

.NET Core now has the efficient `Span<T>` and related types that allow more efficient memory operations. Also, there are some basic parsing primitives for dealing with `Span<Byte>` without having to decode UTF-8.

Kestrel can process requests without using `string` I reckon.

The user of ASP.NET Core, however, gets the request header (request path and HTTP headers) only as `string`s.

Is there a way to get that as `Span<Byte>` also? I have a very low-level application where ideally I would want certain requests make no memory allocations. I'm also just curious.

Comment: nice question!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not at this level, the abstraction for headers is a IHeaderDictionary. Those are parsed before your code runs and we give you a StringValues. There's been various discussions around exposing it as `byte[]`/`Span<byte>` but nothing has come of this as yet.